# Is the ability cost of the commander part of the color identity?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

Consider the card [Rhys the Exiled](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Rhys%20the%20Exiled). Are you allowed to play black (and green) cards in your deck with this commander?

Or are you only allowed to play cards that are the same color as the commander's **cost**? If so, would this then make it impossible to use his ability?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The colour identity of [Rhys the Exiled](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Rhys%20the%20Exiled) is Green and Black.

As per the [Commander colour identity](http://mtgcommander.net/rules.php) rules:

> A card's colour identity is its colour plus the colour of any mana symbols in the card's rules text.

The colour doesn't have to be *just* in the casting cost (which determines the card's *colour*), any mana symbol cost in the rules text counts towards the card's *colour identity*.

See also [Comprehensive Rule](http://www.wizards.com/Magic/TCG/Article.aspx?x=magic/rules) 903.4:

> 903.4. The Commander variant uses color identity to determine what cards can be in a deck with a certain commander. The color identity of a card is the color or colors of any mana symbols in that card's mana cost or rules text, plus any colors defined by its characteristic-defining abilities (see rule 604.3) or color indicator (see rule 204).
> Example: Bosh, Iron Golem is a legendary artifact creature with mana cost {8} and the ability "{3}{R}, Sacrifice an artifact: Bosh, Iron Golem deals damage equal to the sacrificed artifact's converted mana cost to target creature or player." Bosh's color identity is red.

Comment: Side note: The color indicator and the effects of characteristic changing abilities (e.g. Ghostfire) also determine the color.